# Mercurial: "remote: ssl required" even when pushing to HTTPS repository

Tags: apache, ssl, mercurial

I have Apache and hgwebdir.cgi running fine via HTTPS (with a self-signed certificate), I can view the repositories via a browser and clone it locally. I don't know if it'd have any effect, but I'm rewriting the URLs to make them prettier:

```
$ cat .htaccess
Options +ExecCGI
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /public
RewriteRule ^$ hgwebdir.cgi  [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) hgwebdir.cgi/$1  [QSA,L]
```

However, when I try to run hg push to send the changes back, I get this:

```
$ hg push
pushing to https://<repository>
searching for changes
http authorization required
realm: Mercurial
user: virtualwolf
password: 
remote: ssl required
```

Apache is set to redirect all requests that are on HTTP to HTTPS.  The remote server is running CentOS, with Apache 2.2.3 and Mercurial 1.3.1 (both installed via `yum`).

I've done a bunch of searching on this problem, the closest I've come to an answer is [this](http://mercurial.808500.n3.nabble.com/ssl-required-while-trying-to-push-to-https-repository-tp802977p802978.html) but it's referring to NGINX not Apache.

Thanks!

Comment: Try doing the push with `--debug` on the client side, and also please provide the Apache access logs for both the ssl and non-ssl sites.

Comment: Mercurial debug log is [here](http://virtualwolf.org/dump/mercurial_debug_log.txt), Apache log is [here](http://virtualwolf.org/dump/apache_log.txt). There's no non-SSL logs, as everything is going to SSL to begin with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So it turns out the problem was the same as described [here](https://bz.mercurial-scm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1274). It wasn't anything directly to do with Mercurial, but was oddness on Apache's end.

I had to copy the `SSLEngine On` and associated `SSLProtocol`, `SSLCipherSuite`, `SSLCertificateFile`, and `SSLCertificateKeyFile` directives from my separate "Enable SSL" Apache configuration file to my Mercurial virtual host file, even though everything else was working quite happily via HTTPS.

Answer (score 15):

You can resolve this problem by running hg server like this (no push ssl):

> hg serve --config web.push_ssl=No --config "web.allow_push=*"

Answer (score 4):

Add this lines to your central repository where you want to push

```
[web]
push_ssl=False
allow_push=*
```

Needless to say, this is rather unsafe, but if you’re on a nice protected LAN at work and there’s a good firewall and you trust everybody on your LAN, this is reasonably OK.